# Solving CNF using Prolog

Tags: prolog, conjunctive-normal-form, clpb

While learning Prolog, I tried to write a program solving CNF problem (the performance is not an issue), so I ended up with the following code to solve `(!x||y||!z)&&(x||!y||z)&&(x||y||z)&&(!x||!y||z)`:

```
vx(t).
vx(f).
vy(t).
vy(f).
vz(t).
vz(f).

x(X) :- X=t; \+ X=f.
y(Y) :- Y=t; \+ Y=f.
z(Z) :- Z=t; \+ Z=f.
nx(X) :- X=f; \+ X=t.
ny(Y) :- Y=f; \+ Y=t.
nz(Z) :- Z=f; \+ Z=t.

cnf :-
   (nx(X); y(Y); nz(Z)),
   (x(X); ny(Y); z(Z)),
   (x(X); y(Y); z(Z)),
   (nx(X); ny(Y); z(Z)),
   write(X), write(Y), write(Z).
```

Is there any simpler and more direct way to solve CNF using this declarative language?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider using the built-in predicates `true/0` and `false/0` directly, and use the toplevel to display results (independently, instead of several subsequent `write/1` calls, consider using `format/2`):

```
boolean(true).
boolean(false).

cnf(X, Y, Z) :-
        maplist(boolean, [X,Y,Z]),
        (\+ X; Y ; \+ Z),
        (   X ; \+ Y ; Z),
        (   X ; Y ; Z),
        (   \+ X ; \+ Y ; Z).
```

Example:

```
?- cnf(X, Y, Z).
X = true,
Y = true,
Z = true .
```

**EDIT**: As explained by @repeat, also take a serious look at CLP(B): Constraint Solving over Booleans.

With CLP(B), you can write the whole program above as:

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).

cnf(X, Y, Z) :-
        sat(~X + Y + ~Z),
        sat(X + ~Y + Z),
        sat(X + Y + Z),
        sat(~X + ~Y + Z).
```

Please see the answer by @repeat for more information about this.

Comment: I am using Gnu Prolog 1.3, when I run the code (after defining the maplist predicate), I get some exception. Does it run on other compilers?

Comment: Add the rule "false :- fail." if your system does not yet support false/0. Recent development version of GNU Prolog (1.4), YAP and SWI all have it, among others.

Comment: OP changed the question after my answer, which truthfully translated the original question ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Look up "lean theorem prover" (such as [leanTAP](http://www.uni-koblenz.de/~beckert/leantap/) or [leanCoP](http://www.leancop.de/)) for simple, short theorem provers in Prolog.  Those are designed to use Prolog features to the best possible advantage.  Although provers like that use first-order logic, CNF is a subset of that.  There are dedicated SAT solvers for Prolog as well, such as [this one](http://www.soi.city.ac.uk/~jacob/solver/).

Answer (score 2):

**Use [clpb](/questions/tagged/clpb)!**

```
:- use_module(library(clpb)).
```

To check if some Boolean expression is satisfiable, use [`sat/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=sat/1):

```
% OP: "(!x||y||!z) && (x||!y||z) && (x||y||z) && (!x||!y||z)"
?- sat((~X + Y + ~Z)*(X + ~Y + Z)*(X + Y + Z)*(~X + ~Y + Z)).
sat(X=\=X*Y#Z).
```

No concrete solution(s) yet... but a residue that's *a lot simpler* than the term we started with!

To get to concrete truth values, use [`labeling/1`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=labeling/1):

```
?- sat(X=\=X*Y#Z), labeling([X,Y,Z]).
   X = 0, Y = 0, Z = 1
;  X = 0, Y = 1, Z = 1
;  X = 1, Y = 0, Z = 0
;  X = 1, Y = 1, Z = 1.
```